# what is the best practice to handling Session and SessionFactory in Hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I'm building a Java desktop application, (single thread application),

Should I use a global factory session for the whole application session, e.g. from the start of activity (when user open the application) until the user closes the application?
and use a session for each user action on the database.

or should I use one session for the whole application session?

Comment: @NathanHughes
Will do.

Answer (score 0):

Use an application wide *SessionFactory* and an individual Session for every task. I was stuck as ***SessionFactory* must be instantiated in the main Thread of the application** so it stays alive throughout the application runtime.